# Darken the background on a hover

Tags: html, css, sass

again for my website, I want to make a hover on an div class, when you put your cursor on it, his scale gets bigger, I archieved this, now I want it to add like an '!important' cause as you can try here : http://stefanspeter.fr/about-test.html , the middle div for example get his text cuts on the side. I want to fix this problem first, then I would like to darken everything around this window, and to be fair I don't have a clue about how to make that happens.

I tried to add an !important tag, not knowing if it would work, and the way I did wasn't working actually.
Here is the code I'm using now :

```css
.job {
  background: #515151;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: #eece1a 5px solid;
}

.jobzoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="job jobzoom col-sm">
  <h3>Alternance chez <a class="link-2 about-link" href="www.hb-digit.com" target="_blank">HB-Digit</a> et <a class="link-2 about-link" href="https://www.efficom-lille.fr/" target="_blank">Efficom</a></h3>
  <hr class="about-hr" />
  <h4 class="text-secondary">Août 2019 - Août 2020</h4>
  <hr class="about-hr" />
  <p>
    Je suis actuellement en alternance chez HB-Digit sous l'école supérieur Efficom.<br /> Mes principales missions :
    <ul>
      <li>Développement de services web (Drupal8, php, bootstrap, twig, JS, jQuery...)</li>
      <li>Gestion relation client via méthode Agile (Jira)</li>
      <li>Etablissement et respect des cahiers des charges</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
```

Actual output : hover get the scale correctly 
Expected : darken the background while it's hovering, stopping the cut by the others div surrounding it.
Thank you

Comment: add `z-index: 10;` to put hovered div in front.

Comment: Please include all the code required (html and css) to reproduce your problem. Sounds like you need a container with `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: And fix your conjugation: `je me suis demandé ce qui m'attiré`...

Comment: @HiddenHobbes I added it, you can just copy past the same one to try it

Comment: @ManUtopiK sorry it's just a draw for now, haven't checked the syntax at all yet, i just typed quickly to see if I like :)

Comment: The ```z-index:10;``` made the job perfectly, I forgot about this function, it's been a while I didn't do css. Any tips for the darken background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the text being cutted on the side you already solved.
So, here is the solution for the dark background.

First, add a div inside `.about-info` element as the last one. Use `.dark-element` class to it:

```
<div class="about-info">
    <!-- ... --> 
    <div class="dark-screen"></div>
</div>
```

Then, let's add CSS in order to create the effect.

You are going to make it fixed, fill the whole screen, invisible if no `.job` element is being hovering, but will appear when any element is hovered.
So we can use some properties like `transition`, `visibility`, `point-events` and `opacity`. Also, the selector `~` to select siblings (that are after the element, that's why we put it at the end) will be very useful:

```
.dark-screen {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: black;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.76s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.job:hover ~ .dark-screen {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: Worked amazingly well, thank you for the work, that exactly what I was looking for !